# How to create a trigger to call the procedure with an update statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I need to write a procedure and update trigger. When any update is done on the table, the trigger should make a call to the procedure. Procedure should update the changes in another table. In that another table old value, updated value should be there.

Comment: Do you specifically need to update the other table, (that is, an SQL [`UPDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm) statement), or do you just want to capture the change history somehow?

Comment: I just want to capture the update history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described sounds like an *ordinary* logging; you don't really need a procedure, trigger does it all. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table emp_log (empno number, sal_old number, sal_new number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bu_emp
  2    before update of sal on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into emp_log (empno, sal_old, sal_new)
  6    values
  7    (:new.empno, :old.sal, :new.sal);
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> select empno, ename, sal from emp where ename = 'KING';

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING             5000

SQL> update emp set sal = 7000 where ename = 'KING';

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from emp_log;

     EMPNO    SAL_OLD    SAL_NEW
---------- ---------- ----------
      7839       5000       7000

SQL>
```

**[EDIT, after reading a comment]**

Homework, eh? So - create a procedure:

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_emp_sal_log
  2    (par_empno in emp.empno%type, par_sal_old in emp.sal%type,
  3                                  par_sal_new in emp.sal%type)
  4  is
  5  begin
  6    insert into emp_log (empno, sal_old, sal_new)
  7    values
  8    (par_empno, par_sal_old, par_sal_new);
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bu_emp
  2    before update of sal on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    p_emp_sal_log(:new.empno, :old.sal, :new.sal);
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> update emp set sal = 2000 where ename = 'KING';

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from emp_log;

     EMPNO    SAL_OLD    SAL_NEW
---------- ---------- ----------
      7839       5000       2000

SQL>
```

Comment: I must use a procedure . It is a compulsory thing.

Comment: Here you have used only salary..What if the table has name,sal,date_of_birth,etc.. ..There you will be updating any of these value...so it should be given dynamically.

Comment: Include all columns whose values you want to log into the trigger (or the procedure). Optionally, remove the `of` part of the `before update of sal on emp` clause if you don't care which column exactly was updated.

Comment: Thank you..The same thing I have did but made a mistake while calling procedure.

Comment: @Dharani.C If the answer is up to your satisfaction, why not upvote and mark as the correct answer, this will help others in the community to understand the correct answer and most importantly a token of appreciation to the people who contribute here voluntarily.

Comment: @user75ponic .. I tried to upvote but as i am new user and i have reputations less than 15 it will not be displayed.

Comment: @Dharani.C Upvoting and accepting are two different things. You should be able to accept the correct answer to your question regardless of your reputation score.

Comment: Yeah I did now. Thanks @WilliamRobertson